# Java libGDX, error while loading ttf font

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i make a simple game in libgdx but font loading didn't work.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: font.ttf (Internal)
```

This is the code:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = 12;
        font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

I use Android Studio

Comment: What folder is font.ttf located in? it should be in the android/assets folder.

Comment: My bad, one letter was a big and i don't see this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution. Just use BitMapFont generator located in `gdx-tools-1.6(version)` and save the generated font in `android/assets`.

```
BitmapFont yourFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fontname.bmp"));
yourFont.draw(batch, "This is how you have to use fonts in libGDX", 0,0);
```

Good luck!